# Is it possible with DOCKER (or on the host) to detect an HTTP request and then redirect if the main server is down ? How?

Tags: docker, nginx, redirect, devops

I'm sure this is possible somehow, but never really had a need to do so previously.  I have a bunch of Docker containers that run on an UBUNTU host.  One of the containers is an NGINX server that serves as a webserver and reverse proxy.  What I would like to do is setup some sort of 'switch' or mechanism on the host or preferably another device that does something like described below.  The server does have production and development versions of the web applications, so I really just want to set a header if it is running but in maintenance.

---

Set up something on the host other device that indicates or detects the state of the NGINX server.

```
a.  Running normally. 
b.  Running but undergoing maintenance (would have to be manually set into that mode)
c.  Not running.
```

Depending upon the state in 1 it would do the following:

```
a.  Just pass the request through to the server.
b.  Pass through the request, but possibly set a header or something to indicate it is in maintenance mode.
c.  Redirect the request to an external URL, basically the public facing page for the business.
```

Not really sure how to approach that since it seems that I would need an HTTP listener on the host, or possibly on a router or firewall or other device (we have a Fortigate and a Watchguard).  That would check the HTTP request, and then take the appropriate action based upon what "mode" we are in.  The UBUNTU host is pretty much bare bones, i.e. without Apache or another web server because everything is pretty much in the Docker package.

If I were to set that up on the Debian host, seems like we could just have an environment variable that defaults to PROD and then just set it to DEV when we are working on the code, and then set it back to PROD when we are done, and then the process would.

1. ping the DOCKER NGINX instance to see if it is running (i.e. status code).
2. if it is running and PROD, just forward on.
3. if it is running and DEV, set a header to indicate so and forward on.
4. if it is not running, redirect externally.

If the server is completely down though, that would fail.

Any ideas as to how to actually do that ?  Ideally the 'processor' would not reside on the UBUNTU server at all and would always be running.

Comment: The most Docker does on its own in this space is to notice if the process in a container has exited and if so restart it.  The reverse of this is that you also don't need a Docker-specific tool to do this sort of monitoring.  Are you trying to build a tool for this, and if so, what have you tried already?

Comment: I am trying to build a tool.  I don't really need or want a Docker one.  Docker just runs the server.  Some apps on the NGINX Docker are Laravel, in which case there actually is a maintenance mode option via php artisan, if the server is actually running (see https://blog.devgenius.io/laravel-maintenance-mode-a2875028977d).  Just trying to figure out what the options are, either on the host, when NGINX is down, or on our network somewhere.

Comment: @DavidMaze  This will actually work well enough for now:  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#maintenance-mode  Laravel framework has a built-in php artisan command to do something like that if the webserver is actually running, but under maintenance.  Tried it, and I can just use the Admin web interface to execute the php artisan command from the web app.  It works.